# How to disable tsserver check on JS file

Tags: neovim, lsp, filetype-javascript, mason

I am a newbie to neovim, so please bear with me.

I am using Mason to configure my LSP servers. For Javascript I use tsserver. However I am getting error/hint 'Could not find declaration file for module foobar'.

As I understand this error comes from the tsserver, looking for a file with the types declaration of the module.

I am, however, writing pure javascript, so I do not have types declarations and since I am working on company project, I can not create one. I also can not include tsconfig or jsconfig file for the same reason.

Is there a way to tell tssserver in lspconfig, 'hey, do not check types in javascript' or some other setting that can be done specifically in the plugin config file?

Thank you very much for your time